# Parse.com Arduino Yun SDK Quickstart tutorial not working

Tags: parse-platform, arduino, arduino-yun

I have followed the quickstart tutorial step by step on this link https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#embedded/arduinoyun .

Here is my output on the Aruino Yun's serial monitor:

```
Parse Starter Project 
Response for saving a TestObject:
Test object id:
Push Installation ID:4b3b82af-8d39-4413-b4e0-.............................
```

(Test Object ID response is empty. and Push Service started successfully and it gave a valid Installation ID which is the same when I run the code multiple times. )

On clicking the "Test" button in the bottom of the page, I get the following error on the website:

```
"Can't find any registered devices yet..."
```

I know I am missing something but can't figure out what.
I am using the same Parse application which I have used successfully to send Push notifications on my iOS App and Windows App.

I need my Arduino Yun is receive push notifications.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am encountering the same issue.

Comment: Nope. Looks like this is a very common issue. I also need this sorted out pretty soon. You could upvote the question to gather some attention?

Comment: When I run the Examples > Bridge > WiFistatus it confirms my Yun is connected to WiFi. However, like you it appears, my ParseResponse object comes back empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a breaking method in Arduino's Bridge library 1.6.3. This problem has been fixed, but will require you manually updating your Bridge library.

To resolve this issue you must run Library Manager and update Bridge library from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1

To do this choose Sketch -> Include Libary -> Manage Libraries. This will launch Library Manager, then find Bridge Library and press Update button.

Full conversation is here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-embedded-sdks/issues/13