# arduino yun to parse.com starter project not working

Tags: parse-platform, arduino, arduino-yun

I'm trying to run the arduino starter project from parse.com and like other people i have found the object id blank [Parse.com Arduino Yun SDK Quickstart tutorial not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597812/parse-com-arduino-yun-sdk-quickstart-tutorial-not-working)

in the serial monitor i get this response

Parse Starter Project

Response for saving a TestObject:

Test object id:

However i've tried everything i can think of, updated the bridge library, tried various different versions of the IDE and of the bridge library. I'm running windows. I've tried 1.6.1, 1.6.3, 1.6.5 and i've tried several versions of the bridge library. I'm at a loss. Anyone else encountered this issue and have an ideas?

Comment: Try here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/ you will find more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to fix it!

The issue was with the embedded SDK. If anyone struggles with the same probelm here are the steps i took:

1. Download WinSCP.
2. Connect to the arduino using SSH in WinSCP (username root)
3. copy across the two embedded parse.com arduino files (make sure they are in the correct root folder
4. Download PuTTY and use this to open the arduino command line
5. call opkg install *.ipk to install the SDK files

That seems to have sorted the problem, they weren't installed properly before